# How can I reuse code for similar trait implementations?

Tags: rust

I have a few traits with default implementations that require the same methods, which happen to be field getters.

```
trait AddPosition<T: Display>{
    fn x(&self) -> T;
    fn y(&self) -> T;
    fn add(&self){
        println!("{:}", self.x()+self.x());
    }
}

trait SubPosition<T: Display>{
    fn x(&self) -> T;
    fn y(&self) -> T;
    fn sub(&self){
        println!("{:}", self.x()-self.y());
    }
}
```

Instead of manually repeating the same code for each trait implementation, can I have something like this?

```
impl AddPosition<i32>, SubPosition<i32> for Point{
    fn x(&self) -> i32{ self.x }
    fn y(&self) -> i32{ self.y }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option is probably to factor out the fact that your objects can have a position:

```
trait Position<T: Display> {
    fn x(&self) -> T;
    fn y(&self) -> T;
}

// trait AAA: BBB --> means AAA must implement BBB
trait AddPosition<T: Add<Output=T> + Display>: Position<T> {
    fn add(&self){
        println!("{:}", self.x()+self.x()); // ?
    }
}

trait SubPosition<T: Sub<Output=T> + Display>: Position<T> {
    fn sub(&self){
        println!("{:}", self.x()-self.y()); // ?
    }
}

struct MyPosition {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Position<i32> for MyPosition {
    fn x(&self) -> i32 { self.x }
    fn y(&self) -> i32 { self.y }
}
impl SubPosition<i32> for MyPosition {}
impl AddPosition<i32> for MyPosition {}
```

[(Playground)](http://is.gd/jcZNbm)

However, I fail to understand how your code really makes sense (`?` annotated lines). If this is just for the sake of the minimal example, this is totally fine; however, if this is meant for any serious code, you may want to look into the `Add` and `Sub` trait, which will allow you to benefit from operator overloading `+` and `-`. Even if you don't use those traits directly, they may inspire you for meaningful signatures of a potential `add(&self, rhs: &P) -> P` function (where `P: Position<T>`).

Comment: And how I should `impl` AddPosition and SubPosition then?

Comment: See edit, which includes an example of struct implementing AddPosition and SubPosition.

Comment: (Adjacent question for another Rustacean: how is the potential name clash `x` as a field vs. `x()` as a method handled? I expected a compiler error here.)

Comment: BTW, what does `Add<Output=T>` Output means?

Comment: [`Add`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ops/trait.Add.html) has a type parameter `RHS` defaulted to `Self` (so I didn't have to explicitly specify it) and an [associated type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/associated-types.html) `Output`, which specifies here the result of method `add()`. So if my type X is `Add<RHS=Y, Output=Z>`, I will be able to call `(some X) + (some Y)`, which desugars as `(some X).add((some Y))` and get some `Z`.